# Excel VBA exception pass back to C# project

Tags: c#, vba, exception, office-interop

In my C# project I am using Office Interop to call a VBA procedure.  Sometimes it will crash and therefore hang.  I want to pass the crash back to the C# project so that I can log it and close the project effectively.  What is the best way to do this?

Here is the code that I use to call VBA Procedures:

```
CurrentWorkbook.ReportError = (excelApp.Run("CleanMRP", CurrentWorkbook.Company, CurrentWorkbook.ReportType, CurrentWorkbook.TimePeriod, CurrentWorkbook.Version, CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + CurrentWorkbook.FileName, CurrentWorkbook.HeaderRow) == true ? true : CurrentWorkbook.ReportError);

excelApp.Run("addPipePlus", CurrentWorkbook.Version, CurrentWorkbook.HeaderRow);
```